# Changing Types in logstash csv-output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have written a logstash conf file for writing from elasticsearch query to csv files.

I have a field **"f1" : 0.000500021**
while writing into the csv it changes it to scientific notation like **0.500021E-3** . I dont want this. I would like it to store it in the way it receives from elasticsearch.

```
output{
        stdout{
                codec=>"json_lines"
        }
        csv{
                fields=>["c1", "f1", "c2","f2", "c3"]
                path=>"output/test.csv"

        }

}
```

Comment: does the `stdout` output give `0.000500021` or `0.500021E-3`?

Comment: stdout gives 0.000500021